# Make [genetic] a synonym of [genetic-algorithm]?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

I just discovered the [genetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/genetic) tag. It seems to be ~80% composed of questions about [genetic-algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/genetic-algorithm)s, ~10% questions about [genetic-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/genetic-programming), and ~10% questions that belong in [genetics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/genetics) or [bioinformatics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bioinformatics) (whether the genetics tag really offers anything above-and-beyond bioinformatics is a separate question).

[genetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/genetic) is a vague tag name, and is strictly less informative than using any of these more specific tags, so one way or another I think it should go.

From a re-tagging perspective, making [genetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/genetic) a synonym of [genetic-algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/genetic-algorithm) seems simplest, as that is by far the most common use of it. However, I worry that this is un-intuitive - genetic as a word could have many other meanings (albeit few that are terribly relevant to SO). Technically, synonymizing it to [evolutionary-algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evolutionary-algorithms) would encompass both genetic algorithms and genetic programming, but it would be even less intuitive. Another option would be to just burninate it and fix all of these things manually.

Which of these options would be most appropriate?

Comment: Better not a synonym but a manual burning of the tag, to sort things out and make sure it stays sorted. As it's just 102 questions, that should work.